# Custom Drawable with icons on top and bottom in Andoid Studio

Tags: android, graphics, android-drawable, styling

I want to create something like this images and i have a lot of drawables like this one. Please help. thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuwty.png)

Comment: There are many ways for you to achieve that. I'd say the simplest, in my opinion would be to create a RelativeLayout, inside it put 2 ImageViews at the desired location (you can use alignParent end, top, bottom, start for this specific case) and another layout with the desired border, that will create the effect you want. Do note that you'll need to create the border view first for the images to be above it and create it last if you want the images to be below it

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for making border :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid
       android:color="@color/white"/>
   <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
       android:color="@color/app_color"/>
   <corners
       android:radius="@dimen/dp_10"/>

</shape>
```

And use imageView for TopLeft and BottomRigth corners. For making rounded shape of image you may also use cardView.